# How to diagnose hard drive space problem with df, du and/or Disk Usage Analyzer

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, disk-usage

When I checked how much space I have on my HDD I found it to be 300+ from 400 something. The thing is that I recently did a HDD recovery to get back my files and it worked, but then I decided to delete them, so I am thinking that either the deleted files are still there somewhere or something else is going on.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: di you empty the trash?

Comment: Please post the output of df command

Comment: @ravery yes i checked nothing was in it

Comment: @PawelDebski  http://imgur.com/a/XD7L0

Comment: Can you please open Disk Usage Analyzer, select root filesystem and try to pin-down what's eating up your disk space...

Comment: @PawelDebski i did that and the highest file i saw was  24.6 gb , is ther any way i can kind of format the laptop without deleting the ubuntu ?

Comment: Not the one I know about. Anyway please post a screenshot like this: http://pdebski.tumblr.com/post/161940411968/ubuntu-disk-usage-analyzer-is-a-neat-tool-to-find so we can find where exactly the most disk space is used. You can also use du -s for the same purpose.

Comment: @PawelDebski  first : http://imgur.com/a/QRtGU       second :  http://imgur.com/a/m45rI      third :   http://imgur.com/a/W6R5v

Comment: Now we are almost there - I'd still drill-down into .cache and /var dirs and check. If you were thinking about re-installing Ubuntu most of the data there can be safely removed. You can also open 2 other questions like "Which parts of $HOME/.cache can be safely removed" and "... /var ..." respectively.

Comment: The `/var` folder often also has cache (e.g. downloaded packages). But due to the discrepancy of what 'Disk Usage Analyser' shows (24.6 gigabytes vs 444.6), you may need to run something as root to show what is using space (e.g. `sudo du -m / --max-depth 1`) which probably will that the `/var` or `/tmp` folder is using more than shown - or you managed to delete stuff between https://i.imgur.com/AmtPFmj.png and https://i.imgur.com/s0OUIHQ.png

Comment: @PawelDebski thank you very much  i already formated my HDD and reinstalled ubuntu  17.04 i didnt have much time since i got to be somewhere with the laptop and other things where going on  thanks for surporting i hope this becomes usefull in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

To search for files and folders that take up a lot of space on the hard drive - I ran the command:

```
root# du -h / > list-disk.txt
```

The file (list-disk.txt) will contain the contents of your disk with the size. Then it is already possible - to decide what to remove.

Comment: thank you very much  i already formated my HDD and reinstalled ubuntu  17.04 i didnt have much time since i got to be somewhere with the laptop thanks for surporting i hope this becomes usefull in the future :)